# How to create pagination for a JSON data structure to be used in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'never used pagination before, and I am finding it hard to grasp.

so, I am using an application that returns results in xml format, I am converting those results into a JSON data structure which I am then feeding to datatables. I will just show the array of objects code to display data structure.

```
  rcpObj.push({
                    "id"            : i.@id.toString(),
                    "cmOneID"       : i.@cmOneID.toString(),
                    "email"         : i.@email.toString(),
                    "name"          : i.@name.toString(),  
                    "jurisdiction"  : i.@jurisdiction.toString(),  
                    "blackList"     : i.@blackList.toString(),                     
                    "rm"            : i.@rm.toString(),
                    "lawfulBasis"   : i.@law.toString(),
                    "subscriptions" : rcpSubs.toString(),          
                   });
```

So you can view the structure here https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/y23424892
**sample**:

```
[

  {
    "id": "13297734",
    "cmOneID": "134891",
    "email": "13300339@email.com",
    "name": "F13300339 S13300339",
    "jurisdiction": "SCPB - LON",
    "blackList": "0",
    "rm": "Domenica Zampatti",
    "lawfulBasis": "Consent given",
    "subscriptions": "3218160,3218150,15656200,3218161"
  },
  {
    "id": "13218386",
    "cmOneID": "500131",
    "email": "500131@email.com",
    "name": "500131 - First Name 500131 - Last Name",
    "jurisdiction": "Guernsey",
    "blackList": "0",
    "rm": "Euan Dangerfield",
    "lawfulBasis": "None",
    "subscriptions": ""
  }]
```

Currently I am hardcoding in my query the number of results to limit (currently 1000), I was wondering what structure should the JSON response be so that I can paginate say 100k responses in batches of 1000. if you guys can provide some samples? to enlighten me that would be great.

Here is the docs for datatable. https://datatables.net/manual/server-side
ps. I don't mean navigation pagination, but rather paginated json response.

**update**
So i built an API that takes 2 params, &startLine=0&lineCount=3 but not sure if this is sufficient?

[image]

As this website shows it requires links for each pagination, they seem to be grouped (https://reqbin.com/req/yqyqa5ve/json-pagination-example)

```
...
"links": {
  "prev": "/echo/get/json?page=1&limit=50",
  "next": "/echo/get/json?page=3&limit=50"
}
...
```

Comment: Your JSON will look identical.   The server-side code that generates the JSON should partition the data accordingly, then convert that data to JSON.

Comment: The application does not have the logic to return paginated response, I need to build that, so I need to understand the structure of a paginated response in order to build it.

Comment: Imagine you have an array of 100 records and want to return them in pages of 10 - what would that array look like?   It would look exactly the same just it would have 10 records.  That's what you need to do with your JSON.  Datatables doesn't have any special "paging" details for the details, it requests records 1-10 and that's what you give it.

Comment: ah, ok, but then uhmm where do I incorporate the logic so that my query then return the next batches through URL? like 2nd, 3rd,4th

Comment: The structure of the paginated response is in the link you already provided in your question - with [example data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data). So, where do you need to write your logic to build this response...? In your server-side code - the code which creates the Ajax response. When you say "_I am converting those results into a JSON data structure_", where are you doing that? What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: I've updated my question with the endpoint I created that filters based on url param values

Comment: Thank you for the update, but how does this relate to what [DataTables expects](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) you to be using? I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do, here.